# How do I obtain the current build flavours name?

Tags: android, gradle

I'm using Gradle to auto-increase the versionCode of my Android App when I'm doing a release build.
I have a properties file for each build flavor that is stored in the build flavors folder. How do I know which build is currently executed? If I'm doing a 'gradle app:strawberryRelease' I want to obtain the string 'strawberry'.

Alternatively: Can I get the path to the flavor's folder?

My current 'solution' for this:
Taking all build variants and put a 'doFirst' on it's assemble task and in that store the variant somewhere.

But there must be a cleaner way to do this.
Or do I need to go through the command line parameters and parse it myself?

Comment: "How do I know which build is currently executed?" -- by defining one task per build variant. There is no "currently executed". A Gradle file is building up an object model of a build process; it is not an interpreted top-down script.

Comment: Any solutions to this problem ?